# Gradle 6 upgrade causes NoSuchMethodError on getPublishableFiles

Tags: gradle, artifactory, maven-publish

### Background

- Gradle project that uses maven-publish and the jfrog artifactory plugins.
- Upgrading from Gradle 5.6.4 to Gradle 6.9.4 (reproducible when upgrading to 6.0).

### Problem

Running the build e.g.

```
./gradlew clean build
```

fails before any tasks are run, because of:

```
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publication.MavenPublicationInternal.getPublishableFiles()Lorg/gradle/api/file/FileCollection;
```

### Code (excerpted)

```
apply plugin: "maven-publish"
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.8.1"
  }
}

publishing {
  publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
      from components.java
    }
  }
}

artifactory {
    publish {
      defaults {
        publications('mavenJava') # This is the line that throws the exception
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Notes

[Someone else ran into the same issue](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/after-updated-from-5-4-1-to-6-6-1-getting-what-went-wrong-failed-to-notify-build-listener-org-gradle-api-file-filecollection-org-gradle-api-publish-ivy-internal-publication-ivypublicationinternal-getpublishablefiles/42640) and the solution was
"Looks I have to update the plugin in root project build.gradle" which didn't quite get me there since it wasn't clear which plugin they were talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded build-info-extractor-gradle to the [latest 4.x release](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfrog.buildinfo/build-info-extractor-gradle) and that fixed the issue.

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.33.13"
  }
}
```